# How to change user input precentage string to float decimals in python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to make input and output like this ?

```
a = float(input("Enter :")) 
b = float(a[:-1])/100
print (b)
```

Wanted output :

Enter :20%

20

Comment: Just remove the `float` conversion in your first line

Answer (score 1):

If you're expecting float number in input then use `((?:\d+\.)?\d+)` pattern to parse number and convert to `float` type

```
import re

num = float(re.findall(r"((?:\d+\.)?\d+)", input("Enter: "))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
a = input("Enter: ") 
b = int(a[:-1])
print(b)
```

(I've tried to remain faithful to your original code as much as I could.)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this code help you:

a = input("Enter :")

b = float(a[:-1])

print (b)

first get string then convert to float without %
when use float function this convert string or int to float type float(20) equal 20.0

Comment: Hi touraj, may I suggest you use [syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274372/16751401), for example using code fences? Your answer will be much easier to comprehend, then.

Comment: Add code formatting, so code parts are move visible

Answer (score 0):

**Simple but not safe**

```py
a = input("Enter :")
b = float(a[:-1])/100
print (b)
```

**Using Regex to Filter**

We can filter the input using regex so that only integer or float format are acceptable.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/ksXrkP/1

```py
import re
a = input("Enter :")
clean_input = re.findall(r'-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?',a)

if len(clean_input):
    b = float(clean_input[0])/100
    print (b)
else:
    print ("format error")
```